# Redux Observable / RxJS: How to create custom observable?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to do websocket setup in an redux-observable epic, and i'm going with an approach similar to this guy: https://github.com/MichalZalecki/connect-rxjs-to-react/issues/1

However, it looks like my first stab at wiring things up isn't working, even though it looks the same as the guy above:

```
import 'rxjs';
import Observable from 'rxjs';

import * as scheduleActions from '../ducks/schedule';

export default function connectSocket(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(scheduleActions.CANCEL_RSVP)
    .map(action => {
      new Observable(observer => {
        // do websocket stuff here
        observer.next('message text');
      });
    })
    .map(text => {
      console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxx: ", text);
      return scheduleActions.rsvpCancelled(1);
    });
};
```

However, I'm getting a `Object is not a constructor` error:

[image]

=== UPDATE ===

Looks like the suggestion to destructure the { Observable } export worked!

Not the only issue is that `text` doesn't seem to cross over to the next  method...

```
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import * as scheduleActions from '../ducks/schedule';

export default function connectSocket(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(scheduleActions.CANCEL_RSVP)
    .map(action => {
      new Observable(observer => {
        // do websocket stuff here
        observer.next('message text');
      });
    })
    .map(text => {
      console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxx: ", text); // prints undefined
      return scheduleActions.rsvpCancelled(1);
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't if this is the problem but `rxjs` doesn't have a default export, so calling `import Observable from 'rxjs'` shouldn't work. You should be using `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'` instead.

Comment: that fixed the error! thanks a lot!

Comment: no clue why but `text` seems to be undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RxJS v5, the `Observable` class is available as named export, not the default export.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Importing from regular `rxjs` will also import *all* of RxJS (adding all operators to the Observable prototype). This is described [in the docs here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#es6-via-npm). If you'd prefer to be more explicit and only import `Observable` itself you can import it directly at `rxjs/Observable`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

---

Separately, you have a couple issues with the way you're mapping your custom Observable.

**First Issue**

You're not actually returning it. hehe. You're missing a return statement (or you can remove the curly braces and use arrow function implicit returns).

**Second Issue**

The regular `.map()` operator does not do anything special when you return an Observable. If you want the custom Observable to be subscribed to and flattened you'll need to use an operator that does flattening of some kind.

The most common two are `mergeMap` (aka `flatMap`) or `switchMap`.

```
action$.ofType(scheduleActions.CANCEL_RSVP)
  .mergeMap(action => {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      // do websocket stuff here
      observer.next('message text');
    });
  })
```

Which operator you need depends on your desired behavior. If you're not yet familiar, you can check out the [documentation on the various operators](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#choose-an-operator) or jump straight to the [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) and [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) docs.

---

If you're adventurous, RxJS v5 does have WebSocket support out of box you can try with [`Observable.webSocket()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-webSocket). It's not documented very well, but you could also take a look at the unit tests, and for simple read-only unidirectional streaming it's pretty self explanatory--provide the URL and subscribe. It's actually *incredibly* powerful, if you can figure out how to use it, that is. Supports bi-directional, multiplex aka complex multiple input/output channels through a single socket. We use it at Netflix for several internal tools with thousands of rps.

Comment: Thanks! this fixed my error. do you have any idea why `text` is undefined?

Comment: you da real mvp! thanks! using `mergeMap` + `return` (as well as your initial suggestion) it

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Demo. Visit at [Create Custom Observable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-observable)